# Factless Fact Table, but with Facts?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling, data-warehouse, fact-table

Problem: I am working with a SaaS company that provides monthly services. We are trying to create a data model to track customer related metrics such as count, signups, cancellations, and reactivations. I’ve done extensive research online, but the closest I’ve found is accumulating snapshots with start/end dates, which doesn’t make sense with a SaaS company where a customer can reactivate an account.

My initial thought is to create a Factless Fact table for customer, however this factless table would also have keys to event dimension tables, I.e. DimSignupType, DimCancellationType, DimReactivationType, etc and boolean measures for isSignup, isCancellation, and isReactivation. I think this is counterintuitive because a factless fact table shouldn’t have facts, but I need track those and feel multiple fact tables is worse because I would have to join them together in the view.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

**Edit based on feedback:** The main goal of this is to create a dimensional model that is maintainable, but also something I create a view for with other dimensional tables that allows less technical users to discover insights with tools like Tableau. At the end of the day I need to provide a large flat view with multiple measures and dimensions that allows for easy analytical discovery. Common questions may be, "How many signups do we have MTD for this customer type vs last mtd?", "How many cancelations did we have due to Non-Payment this month compared to last", "How many reactivations from Non-Payment did we have this month compared to last?", etc. A lot of this meta data comes from Dimension tables I would join to the factless fact table based on keys, however it still requires a focus on Signups, Cancellations and Reactivations being tracked as Facts for reporting purposes. So I don't know the best modelling approach for it that abides by traditional standards. It almost seems like a Snapshot Fact Table that contains keys to dimensional tables that describe events to be aggregated. I just don't know what that would be called.

I feel the most flexible solution in terms of data management and ease of use would be a factless fact table modeled in a daily snapshot manner with "facts" for signup, cancellation and, reactivations that link to types.

Comment: As far as i understood - you can create a customer SCD type2 table with customer history and their status over time. So, the records will look like this `1/1/2020 new-signup` `5/1/2020 cancelled`, `10/1/2020 reactivated`. So, now you have whole history for each customer. Now, you can write SQL to pull count of signup, cancel etc. over time. You can do historical analysis of activities as well. HTH

Comment: Would this be something like a slowly changing fact table? Space is not a concern, so I’d rather take a snapshot like approach to it to make sql easier for less technical users. But concept remains the same, would it be better to have a snapshot like factless fact table that has measures for status changes, or split them up to separate facts and use some kind of bridge table approach?

Comment: My recommendation: do not focus on the concepts and kewords in the first place and start with the *data exploration* and *data modelling*. Whats wrong with a table `(customer_id, product_id, transaction_type, timestamp)`?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I do like the simplicity of this because it enable a transaction type dimension table which would make joins easier for less technical users, however it won't help with the customer count or point in time analysis. I.e. How many signups, cancellations and, reactivations do we have MTD compared to last MTD, while also being able to provide counts by day which can roll up. I should mention the end goal is to provide a large flat view to non-technical end users who can discover analytics in Tableau (or Viz tool of choice)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I edited the post to give more context to my situation. I'm newer to posting questions, I'm usually able to find thing online that I can make match my situations, but I'm stuck here. Given the abundance of SaaS companies, I'm surprised this type of modelling question isn't more prevalent.

Comment: Hi - so you would normally create fact table(s) for these transaction types (1 table if the associated dimensions are roughly the same for all transaction types, a table per transaction type if the dimensions differ). However, based on your edited question you seem to already know this so it's not clear, to me, what you are asking. Why so you feel you need a factless fact table as well, what purpose will it serve?